# What is the term for a line that doesn't touch a function?

Tags: geometry, tangent-line, secant

A line that cuts into a function is a secant line, and a line that just touches a function is a tangent line.

But what is the term for a line that does not touch the function?

Take the parabola: $$y=x^2$$

A secant line would be: $y=2$

A tangent line would be: $y=0$

But what would $y=-2$ be ?

This line does have a special name as I remember reading it somewhere before and being surprised that it had a name. But unfortunately I have since forgotten it.

I keep thinking extraneous line but I can't find that term anywhere in writing.

Comment: I really doubt that it has a name. It doesn't feel useful or significant enough. There may be some archaic term somewhere though.

Comment: I thought that before too, but I came across its name a while ago but have since forgotten it. I'm fairly sure it does have a name.

Comment: We can say "non-intersecting line".

Comment: Were you meaning asymptote?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the direct translation gives the correct answer but here in Italy we say that the line is *external*. Direct translation also can give: *outside* line, but it doesn't sound very good!

Comment: Or in Germany we say Secante, Tangente or Passante.

Comment: Italy is practically the same: Secante, Tangente, Esterna!

Comment: (Comment because this is non worth a separate answer) Translating from the French would give : a non-secant line.

Comment: I think it comes from the Latin language,

Comment: That is nice that we use the same words.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I was thinking the same! Surly they are from latin, from when I studied latin I can recall that Tangente comes from the latin word *tangens-entis* which means "to touch" and Secante from *secare* which means "to cut"

Comment: Yes this is true,nice, Latin language is very importend